# How to I send a Rest Template Request Body with multiple objects in it

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, resttemplate, pojo

I have to send a request body like this

```
{
    "request": {
        "header": {
            "correlationId": "Test",
            "appId": "12345"
        },
        "payload": {
            "leadId": "12345",
            "applicationNo": "",
            "proposalNo": "P123",
            "policyNo": "100",
            "issuanceDt": "01-06-2022",
            "docName": "ABCD.pdf",
            "docType": "Proposal Form"
        }
    } 
}
```

I also have headers "username" and "password".

I have created Models for request, header and payload with respective fields.

How do I send this using rest template?

Comment: Hi! could you please post your current attempt? It's very difficult to offer assistance with a concrete problem without seeing the error you're getting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new HttpEntity, populate it with headers and body and exchange, using RestTemplate like this. Payload - is a class containing your payload, and I assumed you have a builder (you can use just a map, indeed)

```
final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.add("correlationId", "value");
httpHeaders.add("appId", "value");
HttpEntity<Payload> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(Payload.builder()
//bulider population goes here
.build(),httpHeaders);
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,httpEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you. I watched some YT videos and did something similar.

  `request.setHeaderModel(header);`
  `request.setPayloadModel(payload);`

  `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();`
  
  `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();`
  `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);`
  
  `HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);`
  
  `ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity , String.class);`

Trying to figure out how to read response now, but so far i am able to send data properly.

Comment: Create a class that matches a response schema and use it as a generic parameter in ResponseEntity, or try using ObjectMapper to read a value from a string.

Answer (score 0):

For Header, you just need to add parameters in the headers of HTTP request, Payload is what you are looking for, You can define a DTO class having the same JSON structure which will then be automatically deserialized and mapped to your DTO class.

```
public class Payload{
public String leadId;
public String applicationNo;
public String proposalNo;
public String policyNo;
public String issuanceDt;
public String docName;
public String docType;
```

}